# Create an image every X seconds from live stream

Tags: ffmpeg, video, streaming

I want to grab a static image every X seconds (say 2) from a CCTV live-stream.

I tried `ffmpeg -rtsp_transport udp -i rtsp://user:pass@10.100.20.225:554/front -r 1 -vf scale="-1:720" -vframes 1 -y latest.jpg -loglevel error`, which takes around 6 seconds minimum – probably due to protocol negotiations.

So I thought maybe let ffmpeg run continuously – tried adding `-r 1` to achieve this. Or let one ffmpeg instance handle the stream, so initial protocol negotiations only have to occur once and pipe it to another ffmpeg?

Example stream

Comment: I got messed with `select` filter, but it looks like `-r 0.5` works good enough for your needs. Please let me know if my answer solves your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation of [select filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#select_002c-aselect) and [Expression Evaluation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-utils.html), we can select frames by time.

Selecting frame every 2 seconds:

```
ffmpeg -y -loglevel error -rtsp_transport udp -i rtsp://user:pass@10.100.20.225:554/front -vf "select=bitor(gte(t-prev_selected_t\,2)\,isnan(prev_selected_t))",scale="-1:720" -vsync 0 img_%05d.jpg
```

---

Explanations:

- `isnan(prev_selected_t)` - return `1` in the first video frame (and `0` otherwise).
- `gte(t-prev_selected_t\,2)` return `1` if `cur_frame_time - prev_selected_frame_time >= 2`.
- `bitor` applies logical `or` between the two expressions.
- `-vsync 0` - Video sync method `passthrough` - each frame is passed with its timestamp.

---

In case you know the framerate, you can probably select every n frame as described in [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/1274661/selecting-one-every-n-frames-from-a-video-using-ffmpeg).

Assuming framerate is 25fps for example.
Select every 50'th frame:

```
ffmpeg -y -loglevel error -rtsp_transport udp -i rtsp://user:pass@10.100.20.225:554/front -vf "select=not(mod(n\,50))",scale="-1:720" -vsync 0 img_%05d.jpg
```

---

Testing by streaming synthetic RTSP video to localhost:

In the first console execute:

By time:

```
ffmpeg -rtsp_flags listen -rtsp_transport udp -stimeout 1000000 -i rtsp://127.0.0.1:31415/live.stream -vf "select=not(mod(n\,500))",scale="-1:72" -vsync 0 img_%05d.jpg
```

Or:

By frame number:

```
start ffmpeg -rtsp_flags listen -rtsp_transport udp -stimeout 1000000 -i rtsp://127.0.0.1:31415/live.stream -vf "select=bitor(gte(t-prev_selected_t\,20)\,isnan(prev_selected_t))",scale="-1:72" -vsync 0 img_%05d.jpg
```

In a second console execute:

```
ffmpeg -re -f lavfi -i testsrc=size=192x108:rate=25 -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -rtsp_transport udp -f rtsp -bsf:v dump_extra rtsp://127.0.0.1:31415/live.stream
```

---

The example gets a frame every 20 seconds (and resize to 128x72).

Sample output:
`img_00001.jpg`:
[image]

`img_00002.jpg`:
[image]

`img_00003.jpg`:
[image]

---

### Update:

It looks like `-r 0.05` (or `-r 0.5` in your case) also works:

```
ffmpeg -rtsp_flags listen -rtsp_transport udp -stimeout 1000000 -i rtsp://127.0.0.1:31415/live.stream -vf scale="-1:72" -r 0.05 -vsync 2 img_%05d.jpg
```

It's a bit less accurate compared to using select filter.

Comment: Thanks. Can confirm it works fabulously!